# Elastic search date range max, min date

Tags: elasticsearch

Hi my elastic search mapping as below

```
[
    {
    "runTimeMilliSeconds": {
        "type": "long"
    },
    "syslogMessage": {
        "properties": {
            "DATE": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "FACILITY": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "FILE_NAME": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "HOST": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "HOST_FROM": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "ISODATE": {
                "type": "date",
                "format": "dateOptionalTime"
            },
            "LEGACY_MSGHDR": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "MESSAGE": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "PID": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "PRIORITY": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "PROGRAM": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "SOURCE": {
                "type": "string"
            }
        }
    }
    }
]
```

Now I want to find out last six hours data so I write following query

```
{
    "query": {
    "match_all": {
    }
    },
    "aggs": {
    "last_6_hours": {
        "filter": {
            "range": {
                "ISODATE": {
                    "gte": "now-6h",
                    "lte": "now"
                }
            }
        },
        "aggs": {
            "date_wise_logs_counts": {
                "date_histogram": {
                    "field": "ISODATE",
                    "interval": "1h"
                }
            }
        }
    }
    }
}
```

I return results as below

```
{
    "aggregations": {
    "last_6_hours": {
        "doc_count": 1933,
        "date_wise_logs_counts": {
            "buckets": [
                {
                    "key_as_string": "2015-02-10T04: 00: 00.000Z",
                    "key": 1423540800000,
                    "doc_count": 342
                },
                {
                    "key_as_string": "2015-02-10T05: 00: 00.000Z",
                    "key": 1423544400000,
                    "doc_count": 1591
                }
            ]
        }
    }
    }
}
```

But my problem Is that I want to find out max and min time , for example in above output `doc_count = 342` so I want the range from date where this count generate so my desired output as below

```
{
    "aggregations": {
    "last_6_hours": {
        "doc_count": 1933,
        "date_wise_logs_counts": {
            "buckets": [
                {
                    "key_as_string": "2015-02-10T04: 00: 00.000Z",
                    "key": 1423540800000,
                    "doc_count": 342,
                    "max": 1423540800000,
                    "min": 1423537239000
                },
                {
                    "key_as_string": "2015-02-10T05: 00: 00.000Z",
                    "key": 1423544400000,
                    "doc_count": 1591,
                    "max": 1423544400000,
                    "min": 1423540800000
                }
            ]
        }
    }
    }
}
```

From above output I predict that `doc_count = 342` coming from time intrval from `1423540800000` to  `1423537239000`. And I used elastic search version 1.4.0

Comment: Why not just get those values in a post-processing step? I you know the key of each bucket is the end of the interval and you know that the interval is 1h long.

Comment: @soulcheck thanks for your recommendation I forgot simple logic thanks.